# (ZF - Foundation) proves that $\log_2$ can't be infinitely iterated: Alternative proof

Tags: set-theory, alternative-proof

I think I solved Ex. (12) in Chapter I of Kunen's book. It states that ZF *sans* Foundation proves: For every set $X$, 
$$
\aleph(X) < \aleph(\mathcal{P}^3(X)),
$$
where $\aleph(X):= \sup\{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord} : \alpha \text{ injects into } X\}$ is Hartogs' function.

This has [as a consequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247715) that there is no infinite sequence $\{X_n : n\in \omega\}$ such that for every $n$, there is an injection from $\mathcal{P}(X_{n+1})$ into $X_n$. I was delighted to find this last statement, because it is

> an elementary (or easy-to-state) problem, solvable with axioms that do not defy any conservative intuition, but requires a serious development of Set Theory to be attacked.

**My question:** Is my last assertion correct? I mean, do you know any proof that there isn't such a sequence that does not require ordinals and eventually the argument using Hartogs?

I understand that the easier assertion with 4 replacing 3 in the displayed inequation also suffices, but it seems that I still need the same machinery.

Comment: I cannot think of any other way of proving this without effectively proving Hartogs theorem or Lindenbaum's counterpart for $\aleph^*(X)$ (the least ordinal that $X$ cannot be mapped onto).

Comment: @AsafKaragila same here... Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Btw, I'm not so sure about Replacement here. I mean, could it be the case that you can construct in Z some $X_n$ for each (meta-theoretical) $n$ and for each and prove that $\mathcal{P}(X_{n+1})$ injects into $X_n$? (but of course you wouldn't be able to construct the _sequence_). Does this make any sense?

Comment: Well. I have absolutely no idea how models of $\sf Z-Fnd$ look like. But that sounds plausible. But don't take my word on it.